# Getting an Access Token Without User Login in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am working with facebook graph api rsvp_event. I am using javascript SDK. Everything works great when the user is logged in. But when the user is not logged in, it gives an error.

I need information about who is attending a public event. I now understand that I would need an access token to retrieve this information. So, my question is **how do I get the access token if no user is logged in?** Is it impossible or is there a workaround? Could it be done server side using `app_id` and `client_secret`?

I am developing a ColdFusion page, but I can use PHP if needed. I have support for both.

I have heard the term *offline_access_permission*. They have removed this feature. Could it be done when it was still available?

**EDIT:**

Could this be achieved by `test user`? Say, on server side I login via test user, get the event information (Just a "get" request to read who is attending an event) and then log off. On the client side I do the rest ( user login, rsvp to an event).

I don't know much about "test user" or its purpose. Can anyone confirm whether this can be achieved or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need an access token if there's no logged in user?

Comment: @Igy I need to show who are attending a public event regardless user is logged in or not. I updated my question. Can you give me some insight about test users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you actually need the user's access token? According to documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) you may need:

```
- a generic access_token for public events (those whose privacy is set to OPEN)
- a user access_token for a user who can see the event for non-public events
- an app access_token (for non-public events, must be the app that created the event)
- a page access_token (for non-public events, must be the page that created the event)
```

You can get info on how to get those tokens here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/

A good idea could be to store the attending users (in the DB) when you have access to the event - when some user is logged in.

UPDATE for getting the data from FileContent.

I don't know what API response exactly you are referring to, but from my experience they are returning data: 
- serialized using JSON - you need to use DeserializeJSON(), for example like this:

```
local.returnStruct = DeserializeJSON( local.requestResult.FileContent );
```

or

```
local.returnStruct = DeserializeJSON( local.requestResult.FileContent.toString() );
```

- send as something similar to URI. I'm using a function to get that data:

  ```
  function getStructFromQueryString( queryString ) {
      var ret = StructNew();
      var i = 0;
      var key = '';

      for(i=1; i LTE ListLen(arguments.queryString,'&'); i++) {
          key = ListGetAt(arguments.queryString, i, '&');
          ret[ListFirst(key,'=')] = URLDecode(ListLast(key,"="));
      }

      return ret;
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks a million. You just wrote what exactly I needed. I was wondering, what was the use of secret_key if it doesn't grant any permission. I was bound to hardcode the token from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token . It works but not suggested. I wasted enough time with this. I don't know how to thank you enough. Cheers.

Comment: I thought about storing the info in the DB, but it won't show most recent information. Another problem is that, if no logged in user come to this page, it won't show the information at all. But With this the problem is solved:) Thumbs up to you.

Comment: As I am using coldfusion, I have to figure out how to extract the data from the returned information. Can you give me any direction in that as I am not too good with CF struct. Well, it seems the information is returned in a struct and the main data is within Filecontent. How do I separate the `id`, `name` within the Filecontent as they are not struct. Well,it seems I want more and more :P . I don't know why, but I can't mention you.

Comment: Thanks again. Works great. I believe I can manage the rest of the code. It was a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want is a refresh token that can get access tokens when the user is offline, unfortunately facebook does not provide them anymore as far as i know.

To learn more about oauth2 pleas play around with https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ its a very nice tool to understand the oauth2 process.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I would want to do this part without any user interaction( whether they previously logged in or not). Generally this give me an oauth error message when user is not logged in. I don't really understand what do you mean by **refresh token**

Comment: when the user grants you offline access you get a extra token named `refresh token`. This can generate as many access tokens as you want, it is needed because access tokens expire, so you need to get new ones when they do.

Comment: Gert, that isn't something Facebook has implemented