# Get an access token without being connected to facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I need to retrieve a facebook page's list of posts (feed) using their javascript SDK, just like they explain in their docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/{page-id}/posts",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

I need it to be my website's "news section", so users should see it even if they are not connected to facebook.

### The problem

Cool, but there is a problem... It returns: `An access token is required to request this resource.`
Holy cow... I'd like to get some access token for you @facebook, **but my app doesn't make use of your authentication tools/plugins.**
ANYWAY, I tried with [FB.getLoginStatus();](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) but doesn't work, because the only way it can return an `access_token` is if the user is actually connected to the application. *My users may not even be logged to facebook*!

So, ¿How can I get an access_token to be stored into a variable, and later be used to get `/{my-page}/posts`?

I've already payed a look to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449927/getting-an-access-token-without-user-login-in-facebook-graph-api), but it doesn't solves my problem, simply because there are no such "generic tokens".
I've also read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ and that also relies on tokens generated through facebook login methods... So, can't I display a list of fb page's posts in my website, without being connected into facebook, hence an application?

ADD: My app is build with angularJS, I'm not dealing with server-side code. I shall rely purely on javascript methods.

Comment: It seems you have to be authenticated in facebook to use facebook

Comment: Hey, did you find a way to do this? I'm still trying to figure out how to have that page access token and call the api via PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use an page or an app access token, but as you'd be using them on the client-side, neither of them are an option.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

> Note that because this request uses your app secret, it must never be made in client-side code or in an app binary that could be decompiled. It is important that your app secret is never shared with anyone. Therefore, this API call should only be made using server-side code.

I'd strongly recommend to build a simple server-side script (PHP for example) to proxy the request to the Graph API. You could then call this via AJAX for example and load the posts asynchronously (and alse get rid of the FB JS SDK!). There is **NO** way to handle this in a secure manner if you don't want to use FB Login for all of your users (which also doesn't make much sense IMHO).

Comment: Ok, let me recap a bit :D You're suggesting me to build my own API, using PHP (for example), and facebook PHP SDK to target the `/{my-page}/posts` endpoint of facebook API, and then I call my own api from my client, just like `/api/pageFeed` which should return the same object that I'd get if I were logged to facebook and I call `/{my-page}/posts` normally, with an access token ?? (Sorry for the looooong question :D)

Comment: More or less an accurate recap :-) If you're more familiar with JS you could also write a 20 line Node.js script. You can create an eternal page access Token which doesn't need to be refreshed for calling the Graph API

Comment: Let me talk with the back-end crew and I'll come back at you later ;) Btw, what do you suggest: That my API returns the generated token only and I do the rest in JS, or approach the server side script to return the full json object from `/{page}/posts` instead?

Comment: I'd recommend the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's straightforward :)
Since pages' posts are always **public**, it only needs a *valid* access token to retrieve page posts.
Quoting what you've written:

> So, ¿How can I get an access_token to be stored into a variable, and later be used to get /{my-page}/posts?

You only require an access token.
My suggestion would be;
 - Generate an access token for yourself (no extra permission needed)
 - request page-id/posts

This way you don't require other users to be connected to facebook, you can simply requests page-id/posts to retrieve posts with access token you generated for yourself.

I hope it solves your problem :D

**TIP**: As long as posts are **public**, you only require a valid access token, it doesn't need to be user or page specific.

Comment: That should only be done for server-side apps though – exposing an access token that is not for the user currently viewing/using the app in client-side code would be a very bad idea, because everyone could steal it from there.

Comment: And page posts are not “always public” – the page itself might be restricted (age, location, alcohol-related content), or the posts might be “targeted” to specific audiences only.

Comment: @CBore If the access token doesn't have extra permissions, I think it's **OK**. The second case only applies if you're connected to facebook, I guess, and requires page-access token afaik.

Comment: Still, it should not be done this way. (And page posts with limited visibility can be requested using the page access token, _or_ a user access token from a user that satisfies the requirements.)